# Cygwin unable to compile

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin, putty

I just downloaded Cygwin, I've never used it before cause I've always used putty. Cygwin is not letting me compile; I can see the files but it just doesn't let me compile and I do not understand why, am I doing something wrong?

This is what's going on:

```
Christine@Christine-PC ~
$ ls
8.6.c   a.b.c  a.c.c  core    new  2.txt  test.c
9.13.c  a.c    a.out  days.c  new2.c      test.txt

Christine@Christine-PC ~
$ gcc a.c.c
-bash: gcc: command not found
```

Comment: Try to reinstall cygwin and make sure that GCC is being installed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `gcc` if you want to be able to compile. Run `setup` again and select it.

Comment: Where is it under? debug?

Comment: Type `gcc` into the search bar. It's under `devel`.